# Magento 2: While running "vendor/bin/phpcbf" Uncaught Error: Class 'PHP_CodeSniffer\Runner' not found

Tags: magento2.3.1, coding-standards

I have faced issue in `"vendor/bin/phpcbf"` command for resolving custom extension coding standard.

I am using Magento ver.2.3.1

**Running command in project root:**

> vendor/bin/phpcbf "app/code/Namespace/MyModule"

But while running command through below error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'PHP_CodeSniffer\Runner' not
> found in /var/www/html/magento/vendor/bin/phpcbf:17 Stack trace:
>
> ## 0 {main}   thrown in /var/www/html/magento/vendor/bin/phpcbf on line 17

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: can you share a screenshot to get more idea about the error?

Comment: use whole path like this 

`vendor/bin/phpcbf /var/www/html/magento/app/code/Vendor/Module --standard=MEQP2`

Comment: can you provide the coding standard github link to know which coding standard you're using?

Comment: try `phpcbf` command after running this command  cd `magento-coding-standard`

Comment: you can check it by this command `which phpcbf` to see if it's installed or not

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inside project

*Install*

```
composer require squizlabs/php_codesniffer:^3.4

// magento ruleset
composer require magento/magento-coding-standard

// auto ruleset installer – automatically pickup 'phpcodesniffer-standard' packages
composer require dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer
```

*Usage*

```
// should see Magento2 standard listed
vendor/bin/phpcs -i
vendor/bin/phpcbf -i

vendor/bin/phpcs --standard=Magento2 app/code/Xigen/Vehicle
vendor/bin/phpcbf --standard=Magento2 app/code/Xigen/Vehicle

vendor/bin/phpcs --standard=Magento2 app/code/Xigen/Data --report-file="Data.txt"
vendor/bin/phpcbf --standard=Magento2 app/code/Xigen/Data --report-file="Data.txt"
```

Comment: Get error: ERROR: the "Magento2" coding standard is not installed. The installed coding standards are Zend, PSR2, PSR1, PEAR, Squiz, MySource and PSR12

Comment: You're not picking up the magento ruleset which means either second two composer commands didn't work or phpcs you are triggering which can be determined by path is not inside project folder

Comment: This answer does not address the actual error in the question.

Answer (score 0):

This error happens, if phpcs/phpcbf are copyed into the vendor/bin directory.

The reason is, the Package itself is not registering an autoloader, and the code inside the executables is

```
if (is_file(__DIR__.'/../autoload.php') === true) {
    include_once __DIR__.'/../autoload.php';
} else {
    include_once 'PHP/CodeSniffer/autoload.php';
}
```

The first is for it locally, including a custom autoload.php from inside.
The second case I think is going to the include Path, which is only working if globally installed.

To solve you have multiple options.

1.

make sure its symlinked, not copied into vendor/bin/

2.

add the autoload.php file in your project composer.json like this:

```
    "files": [
        "vendor/squizlabs/php_codesniffer/autoload.php"
    ],
```

3.

execute the file directly as `vendor/squizlabs/php_codesniffer/bin/phpcs`

Answer (score 0):

Have the same issue, and fixed with this command:

```
composer global require squizlabs/php_codesniffer:^3.4

composer global require magento/magento-coding-standard
```

As result, my global `phpcs -i` working good
do not need to call it from vendor/bin/phpcs